# How correctly add rhino - Android in Android Studio 3.1.4

Tags: android-studio

When I'm cloning an Android Studio project from github and run it  in Android Studio 3.1.4 in my PC  (Windows 10 Pro).
Runs Ok
buld.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mad_minicalculator.iqrauniversity.minicalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.faendir.rhino:rhino-android:1.4'
}
```

When I rewrite this app  in Android Studio 3.1.4
When I add   compile 'com.faendir.rhino:rhino-android:1.5' in buld.gradle (Module: app),
Indicates an  - Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.

buld.gradle (Module: app)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vitaliebancu.minicalculatoralinasoft"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.faendir.rhino:rhino-android:1.5'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer is noted on your error message. You have to replace 'compile' with 'implementation', since compile has been deprecated and stopped working end 2018.

Indeed, when browsing old libraries, it's common to see still 'compile' on their installation guide, always replace it with "implementation" and you won't have any problems.

Comment: I'd really like to understand why my answer got downvoted where I clearly expain what the problem is and downvotes should be used for technical incorrect answers and spam basically.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
implementation("com.faendir.rhino:rhino-android:1.6.0")
```

and rebuild the project or just resync.